# Trouble running batch file in c#

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, process

I am writing a simple program to make developing Homebrew Gameboy Advanced Games a little easier. 
I have trouble running the batch file which builds the .gba rom, it works properly when double clicking on the batch file but when I run it from the application a command window appears and nothing happens after that.

Here is the code I am using to run the batch file:

```
 var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + New_File.ProjectPath + New_File.ProjectName + @"\build.bat");

        //Do not create command propmpt window 
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

        //Do not use shell execution
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        //Redirects error and output of the process (command prompt).
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        //start a new process
        var process = Process.Start(processInfo);

        //wait until process is running
        process.WaitForExit();

        //reads output and error of command prompt to string.
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

And here is the batch files contents:

```
path=C:\devkitadv\bin

gcc  -o main.elf main.c

objcopy -O binary main.elf main.gba

pause
```

I would really appreciate some help on this, thanks!

Comment: Change first line to `path C:\devkitadv\bin;%PATH%` to prepend the new path to all other paths instead of completely redefine PATH. Specify `gcc` with full path and with file extension in double quotes if this is possible because `gcc` is installed on all computers in same folder. Do the same for `objcopy`. And define also the project directory as working directory in batch file or in C# application for the new process.

Comment: You're redirecting the output, which explains why you're getting a blank command window. And since you have the `pause` command there, the window is going to stay there. If you remove the output redirection, you'll probably be able to see if there's an error message. Most likely, you haven't set the `WorkingDirectory` property in the `ProcessStartInfo`.